# Undefined Constant Issue

Tags: php

I was working on my site yesterday and all the content was appearing fine.  Then today, I refreshed and something has broken.

I'm getting this error on the homepage:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant Page - assumed 'Page' in includes\survey_inside.php on line 19  
Notice: Use of undefined constant Listing - assumed 'Listing' in includes\survey_inside.php on line 20
```

When I look on line 19 the code is:

```
$strPage = $_REQUEST[Page];
if($_REQUEST[mode]=="Listing"){
```

Like I said, everything worked fine yesterday, and I didn't change these lines.  I've been looking around for several hours and am stuck.  Any thoughts on how to proceed with figuring out what happened?

Thanks!

Comment: `$_REQUEST['Page']` and for others

Comment: maybe the version of PHP changed on your server, otherwise put Page in quotes, assuming you actually didn't define Page as a constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to access an array like `$_REQUEST`, you have to use some key (string value). In this case you are calling `$_REQUEST[Page]` and `$_REQUEST[mode]`.

Since `Page` and `mode` are not constant values, you have to use it as a string, so:

```
$strPage = $_REQUEST['Page'];

if ($_REQUEST['mode'] == "Listing") { }
```

Comment: Hi, when I add the '' around the values it has the same error but just shows assumed value 'Page' now.

Comment: What I'm wondering is what to search for to find where the constants may have been defined?  I'm taking over someone else's code just for practice.